# Recorded macro doesn't work on other sheets

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I'm working on a recorded macro that will execute the same action to a lot of similar sheets. If works neatly for the sheet i recorded it on, however, when i try it on other workbooks it doesn't work.
Here's a piece of the code, basically it copies the first column, pastes on a new sheet, removes duplicates and gets the first 6 numbers:

```
Sub Macro2()

    ActiveSheet.Select
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count).Select
    Columns("A:A").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.UnMerge
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(RC[-1],6)"
    Range("B2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B14")
    Range("B2:B14").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Range("D8").Select
End Sub
```

I know it doesn't look good, I'm still learning. I don't get it why it doesn't work on other sheets if it looks so simple.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? I see nothing that is sheet specific. However you should reduce/remove the selections. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/9292/avoid-using-select-or-activate) are some tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting inconsistent results likely due to the use of `.Select`, which it's [best practice to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros).

I've created two variables to store your worksheets, and do what you have above, but without `.Select`. The only thing is, what's the last column `.Insert Shift:=xlToRight` supposed to do?

```
Sub macro2a()
Dim mainWS As Worksheet, newWS As Worksheet

Set mainWS = Worksheets("Sheet1")    ' I assume this is the sheet name of your main worksheet.
Set newWS = Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))

newWS.Columns("A:A").Value = mainWS.Columns("A:A").Value    ' instead of copy/paste, you can set ranges equal if you just need values.
With newWS
    .Columns("A:A").UnMerge
    .Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

    .Range("B2").FormulaR1C1 = "=Left(RC[-1],6)"
    .Range("B2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("B2:B14")
    .Range("B2:B14").Value = .Range("B2:B14").Value ' instead of copy/paste special, just set values equal to remove formulas

    With .Columns("A:A")
        .ClearContents
      '   .Insert shift:=xlToRight  ' What's this line to do?
    End With '.Columns("A:A")

End With 'newWS
newWS.range("D8").Select ' This is okay since it's the end, and we're just using .Select to get to the cell.
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. The last commands delete the first column (with the data i pasted from the other sheet) and include a blank one (odd, but necessary). The data i want remains in the column B as i used the formula LEFT to extract the value i need.

Comment: @Serveira - Okay, I just edited that last line to just clear contents of column A. *Please* note I wasn't sure what sheet should have been the "pasting TO" sheet, vs. the data source, so you may have to tweak the sheets in the code.

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks. I'll try and adapt this to the rest of my code.

Comment: @Serveira - Happy to help! I ***highly*** suggest you review my code and compare to yours and learn how to avoid `.Select`.  I didn't really "do" a whole lot to get it working, all I did was avoid using `.Select`, and used two worksheet variables.  Essentially, to remove `.Select`, just "snug" it back up to the line ending in `.Select`...ie: `Cells(1,1).Select // Selection.Copy` can just be `Cells(1,1).Copy` (just remove `.Select`, `.Selection`).

Comment: Will do! I'm really trying to learn how to code and you guys are helping a lot.